# Ошибка CS1703 при сборке проекта ссылающегося на библиотеку .NET Standard

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

При сборке получаю серию ошибок вот такого вида:

> CSC : error CS1703: Импортировано несколько сборок с одинаковыми удостоверениями: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\ref\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll" и "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6.1\Facades\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll". Удалите одну из повторяющихся ссылок.

Ошибка возникла когда я попытался добавить пакет System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow. Воспроизводится на пустом проекте: создаем консольное приложение, добавляем пакет - и все, уже не собирается.

Используется Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта ошибка вызвана конфликтом механизмов поддержки Portable Class Library и .NET Standard.

Первый находится в файле `MSBuild\14.0\Bin\Microsoft.NetFramework.CurrentVersion.targets`, второй - в файле `MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions.NETFramework.targets`. Делают они одно и то же - добавляют в проект ссылки на "виртуальные" независимые от платформы сборки для того, чтобы компилятор не переживал из-за их отсутствия. А поскольку они делают одно и тоже - то и ссылки на сборки они добавляют одни и те же.

При этом ссылки на PCL добавляются всегда, а ссылки на .NET Standard - только при наличии таких зависимостей.

Если у вас в проекте нет ссылок на PCL-библиотеки, то правильным решением будет прописать следующий ключ в файл проекта:

```xml
    <PropertyGroup>
        <ImplicitlyExpandDesignTimeFacades>false</ImplicitlyExpandDesignTimeFacades>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

Это отключит первый механизм и все заработает.

Если же в проекте такие зависимости присутствуют - то возможно появления следующей ошибки во время компиляции:

> error CS0012: The type 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

Подобные проблемы возможны со следующими сборками (они входят в PCL, но не входят в .NET Standard):

- System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll
- System.Reflection.Emit.dll
- System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration.dll
- System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight.dll
- System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll
- System.ServiceModel.Duplex.dll
- System.ServiceModel.Http.dll
- System.ServiceModel.NetTcp.dll
- System.ServiceModel.Primitives.dll
- System.ServiceModel.Security.dll

В таком случае вместо решения выше можно попробовать создать Target по типу вот такого:

```
<Target Name="ResolvePCLAndNETStandardConflicts"
        DependsOnTargets="ImplicitlyExpandDesignTimeFacades;ImplicitlyExpandNETStandardFacades"
        BeforeTargets="ResolveAssemblyReferences">
  <ItemGroup>  
    <ResolvePCLAndNETStandardConflicts_ReferencePathToExclude Include="@(DesignTimeFacadeDirectories)">
      <RelativeName>%(_NETStandardLibraryNETFrameworkReference.Filename).dll</RelativeName>
    </ResolvePCLAndNETStandardConflicts_ReferencePathToExclude>
    <ReferencePath Remove="@(ResolvePCLAndNETStandardConflicts_ReferencePathToExclude->'%(Identity)%(RelativeName)')" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Comment: Как это сделать?
По первому варианту открыл файл проекта *.csproj в блокноте и вставил `<ImplicitlyExpandDesignTimeFacades>false</ImplicitlyExpandDesignTimeFacades>`, однако изменений не заметил.
По второму варианту даже не знаю, как это сделать. Те файлы target хранятся в системных папках, не связанных с моим проектом и вряд ли хорошо заменять из содержимое.

Comment: @Kosmos а вы ImplicitlyExpandDesignTimeFacades прописали внутрь PropertyGroup или куда попало? Что же до Target - этот элемент спокойно прописывается в файле проекта.

Comment: Внутрь PropertyGroup.
Однако я уже нашел третий вариант решения, описанный здесь: https://github.com/HiP-App/HiP-Forms/commit/b24ad3beed5cf59eee01241d4a21c94ab28833c1 и он сработал.

Comment: @Kosmos разве ExcludeAssets работает в 2015й студии?

Comment: Видимо, нет. Я пользуюсь 2019, и у меня сработало. Даже не обращал внимания на студию автора вопроса. Главное, проблема решена.

Comment: @Kosmos в 2019й студии этой проблемы уже не должно быть. Возможно, у вас была какая-то другая проблема - потому и варианты решения не подходили.